# Sorting Row and Column from Table of Number

Tags: bash

I'm not sure whether someone already ask about this or not, if someone already did forgive me.

I have a chunk of random number (my_number)

```
1 2 5 8 3 4

3 7 5 4 7 2

2 3 7 7 9 1
```

I want to sort them both by row and column:

by row

```
1 2 3 4 5 8

2 3 4 5 7 7

1 2 3 7 7 9
```

by column

```
1 2 5 4 3 1

2 3 5 7 7 2

3 7 7 8 9 4
```

So far, I've tried

```
while read line; do
tr, $'\n' < <(printf -- "%s" "$line") | sort -g | tr $ '\n', | sed 's/,$/\n/';
done < my_number
```

and I also tried some basic command like

```
sort -g my_number

sort -n my_number
```

However, apparently every one of them only sort the first column, the rest still randomly scattered.

Is my idea about sorting both by row then change by column even possible? A help in fixing my code or new code will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Going from:

```
1 2 5 8 3 4

3 7 5 4 7 2

2 3 7 7 9 1
```

to this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 8

2 3 4 5 7 7

1 2 3 7 7 9
```

is not terribly difficult, by correcting your original attempt:

```
while read line; do
    tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $line | sort -g | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,/ /g'
done < the_file
```

The above is not terribly difficult because the input can be processed row by row.

Sorting the values in each column is significantly harder.
One way to do it:

1. transpose the values
2. apply the sorting logic by row (first part of your question)
3. transpose the values

One way to implement transpose:

```
transpose() {
    gawk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) a[i] = a[i] " " $i } END {for (i in a) { print substr(a[i], 2); print "" }}'
}
```

For clarity, let's put the sorting logic in a function too:

```
sort_each_row() {
    while read line; do
        tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $line | sort -g | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,/ /g'
    done
}
```

And then you can do:

```
transpose < the_file | sort_by_row | transpose
```